# How can I make katex work with HTML elements that have an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, katex

I'm using the auto-render extension of katex to render math formulas as they are typed. How can I make this extension work with content editable HTML elements (`textarea`, `input`)?

I've noticed that the katex auto-render extension works fine for HTML elements whose content can't be edited such as a div or a p element. However it doesn't work for content editable elements such as a `textarea` or an `input` element

I've tried using a `div` with the attribute `contenteditable` set to true. This works with a number of caveats so i'd rather not pursue this endeavor

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing the katex auto-render module</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.2/dist/katex.min.css" integrity="sha384-yFRtMMDnQtDRO8rLpMIKrtPCD5jdktao2TV19YiZYWMDkUR5GQZR/NOVTdquEx1j" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.2/dist/katex.min.js" integrity="sha384-9Nhn55MVVN0/4OFx7EE5kpFBPsEMZxKTCnA+4fqDmg12eCTqGi6+BB2LjY8brQxJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.10.2/dist/contrib/auto-render.min.js" integrity="sha384-kWPLUVMOks5AQFrykwIup5lo0m3iMkkHrD0uJ4H5cjeGihAutqP0yW0J6dpFiVkI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            // let contentEditableDiv = document.querySelector("#contentEditableDiv");
            document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {

                renderMathInElement(document.body, {
                    delimiters: [
                        { left: "$$", right: "$$", display: true },
                        { left: "\\[", right: "\\]", display: true },
                        { left: "$", right: "$", display: false },
                        { left: "\\(", right: "\\)", display: false }
                    ]
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea id="content">
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
    </textarea>

    <input type="text" name="" id="" value="$\alpha$">

    $\alpha$
    $\alpha$
    $\alpha$
    $\alpha$

    <p> $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$</p>

    <div>
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
        $\alpha$
    </div>

    <div contenteditable="true" id="contentEditableDiv">try typing some text + math enclosed
        math formulas in here</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm expecting the `$\alpha$` inside the content editable HTML elements (`textarea` and `input`) to be rendered after the `keyup` event

Comment: I don't think you can easily edit the text in the element that contains the rendered output. But it should be doable from the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered result is more complicated than just the text, so you can't directly edit what is rendered in the element. Same way, you can not simply render the formula (HTML elements) inside the text area.

What you can do is to get the value of the input and render it somewhere else.

Say you have:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<input type="text" id="formula" value="c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}" />
```

```
const formulaInput = document.querySelector('#formula');
const element = document.querySelector('#content');
```

Then you can do

```
formulaInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  katex.render(formulaInput.value, element, {
    throwOnError: false
  });
});
```

To render the new content from the input into the desired element.

This is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syxwcg6p/5/).